# translation of 「あえて言えば、....」

Tags: translation, set-phrases

What does the phrase 「あえて言{い}えば」 mean? What are a few example sentences?

Is the following usage correct:
「好きな日本料理{にほんりょうり}はあんまりないが、**あえて言えば** 納豆{なっとう}ですね。」

"I don't really like Japanese food, but if I had to mention something I would say natto."

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Comment: I will be honest.  I am a Japanese speaker but I do not understand what your "Japanese" sentence means.  Are you saying that you do or you do not like natto?

Comment: @l'électeur I am trying to say: "Well, I do not really like any type of Japanese food. However, if I were forced to say something, then I guess I'd say natto."

Comment: See also: [強いて]{しいて}言えば

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「あえて言えば」is often used to mean a kind of weak opinions.
Your sentence looks totally natural to native speakers (including me).

I'll list some example sentences:

- あなたの提案で概ね問題ないが、あえて言えば予算が気になる。(Your proposal looks good as a whole, but I have little worry about its cost.)
- あえて言うほどでもありませんが、家に帰ったら手は洗った方がいい。 (This may be a needless concern, but I think you should wash your hands when you go back home.)

Comment: I'm curious that if 「あえて言う」= "to say something that's needless (to say)", how can 「あえて言うほどでもない」 mean "this may be a needless concern" but not the opposite?